# Perl Handling Directory Separators

Tags: perl, file-io

I really should know this, but I've worked mainly with Linux, Mac OS X and Windows which all use the forward slash (`/`) as a directory separator (Windows can use either `\` or `/`.).

That means when I normally write programs in Perl, I can simply use `/` as the directory separator and everything is fine. However, I know that `File::Spec` is suppose to allow for the *portability* of file separators (whatever that means).

If I am on a system that does not use forward slashes as a directory separator, I understand that users expect to be able to input files with the default separators and see output with the default separators. (For example, a Windows user will input  and expect output to be `C:\Users\smith\Documents` and not `C:/Users/smith/Documents`), but what does Perl do internally?

Can I, despite what the platform may use as a directory separator, simply use forward slashes when I'm dealing with files internally. For example, I have a directory `$dir` and a file called `$file`, and I want to open the file. Can I simply say `$dir/file`, or do I have to use `File::Spec` to concat the name for me?

In fact, do Perl programs **require** forward slashes in directory names? I'm writing a module, and will be delivering file names to the calling program. Should I give the file as `/foo/bar/fubar` or if the system uses colons like the early Macintosh OS, say `:foo:bar:fubar`?

Comment: What are you going to be doing with the paths?  If it is for reading and writing to files, then `/` is fine, and perl will do what you mean.  If you are crafting commands to be parsed by the host computer's command shell or by other programs on that system, then you will need to obey the rules for that platform, and File::Spec can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`perlport`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlport#Files_and_Filesystems) says almost everything there is to say about this subject. That said, systems that can not accept `/` as the path separator are rare, and you might not have that much to gain from using `File::Spec` faithfully everywhere. But also be careful to distinguish internal and external uses of the directory separator. For example, this will work on Windows:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'C:/some/directory/to/some/file';
```

but this might not, because it needs to be processed by the Windows shell:

```
system("C:/some/program.exe C:/some/program/argument.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to Perlport. I did learn something about `unlink` and VMS that was rather interesting. My program is returning file/directory names to a calling program, so I'm not too worried about external names, but I might add the option.